# How can I style/customize connect/middleware-directory output?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm trying to build a simple searching/browsing service for a server and I thought it could be interesting to use Express for that to get familiar with it.

For the problem I'm considering, I have `express@3.4.1` and a very simple `app.js`:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
//var express = require('express')
//, app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function() {
    var hourMs = 1000*60*60;
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: hourMs }));
    app.use(express.directory(__dirname + '/public', {hidden: true, icons: true}));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.listen(1333);
```

How can I style/customize the HTML/CSS that the [`directory` middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/directory.html) produces?

Should I overwrite [`express.directory.html`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/directory.js#L109) in my `app.js` or is there a better/cleaner way?

**Edit:** After looking at the code it seems overriding the function is not the way to go. The file it uses seems rather hard-coded and I may end up copying the whole file to override what I want. So, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract all relevant code from the Express middleware, make your own adjustments, and save it as part of your app (as `./lib/middleware/directory.js` or something).

If you're going to modify the files inside the `node_modules/` directory you can be sure that you'll lose any modifications when you update.

You *could* rewrite `express.directory.html()`, but you might still run into the problem that any updates make it stop working because of internal changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe directly editing the node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/public/style.css and directory.html would be the cleanest way of customizing the default express directory style/html.

Comment: I'm not sure it would survive an update process but it's actually what I'm doing right now...